# Problems using import package with included files that load packages

Tags: xetex, input, standalone, import, relative

I have the following structure (the MWE files here aren't worth it, but they represent something significantly larger I'm working on):

```
test
├── config
│   └── tikz.tex    <-- This file groups related TikZ commands
├── img
│   └── image.tex   <-- Image generated with TikZ for testing purposes
├── mwe.tex         <-- Main .tex file
└── preamble.tex    <-- Common preamble file (for the standalone package)
```

The MWE files are:

mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage{standalone}
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
  Hi there!
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includestandalone{img/image}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

preamble.tex

```
\usepackage{float}
\input{config/tikz}
```

config/tikz.tex

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  pics/circleHi/.style args = {msg #1}{%
    code = {\draw (0,0) circle (2) node at (0,0) {#1};}
  }%
}
```

img/image.tex (Note I'm using the `import` package)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{import}
\subimport*{../}{preamble}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw pic at (-3,0) {circleHi={msg Hi}};
    \draw pic at (0,0) {circleHi={msg there}};
    \draw pic at (3,0) {circleHi={msg friends!}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile the file `mwe.tex` with

```
latexmk -xelatex mwe.tex
```

Everything is fine, and I get the PDF with the following result:

[image: Output of compiling the given project structure.]

However, when I try to compile *only the image* located in `img/image.tex` I get the following error, despite the fact I'm using `\subimport*{../}{preamble}`.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `float.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `import` package? Did I miss something? Is there any other possibility to allow relative paths, in case `import` is not suitable for this scenario?

It's important for me to compile the standalone TikZ graphics, to use them directly in the document and reduce compilation time, without using the `standalone` class as I want the image files in the same folder as the LaTeX sources (for this MWE that doesn't matter, but it does on larger projects).

Thanks in advance! `:)`

Comment: Does using `\subimport{../}{preamble}` work? I think that what is happening is that latex can't find `float.sty` because the `*` option of `\subimport` disables `TEXINPUTS`. Removing the `*` should fix your problem. I haven't tested this because I am too lazy to set up all of your files (sorry!).

Comment: @Andrew I removed it, and it works! `:)` So it seems that's the problem. Please answer and I'll finish this!

Comment: Great. Glad it worked. Have added this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that latex can't find `float.sty` because the `*` option of `\subimport` disables `TEXINPUTS`. Removing the `*` should fix your problem.